# Kendo Grid in mobile as same as desktop

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem with kendo grid in mobile.
when I surf my website with mobile.
kendo grid switch to moblie mode (I think). and it's not good.
surf below link with your moblie.
[Kendo grid demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/)

but when I click on desktop view button.
It looks great.

How can I have kendo grid in mobile as same as desktop view?
without click on desktop view button.

I used bootstrap for responsive page in my project.

your help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless you have specified on the grid mobile: true, the grid doesn't use adaptive rendering for mobile devices.  See docs http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-mobile

Comment: @RobinGiltner : thanks for repond. I didn't specify mobile: true,

Comment: @RobinGiltner: Can I change user agent or anything like that for this solution?

Comment: You shouldn't need to.  The sample you linked looked/worked the exact same for me on desktop or mobile (Android).

Comment: @RobinGiltner That's not true, you can't see 2 columns in moblie view

Comment: All 4 columns show up on my device.

Comment: Ah, I see.  It is hiding columns based on the width of the view port.  It does that on desktop if you make your browser real narrow, it will eventually hide those columns that don't have a width specified.